# List of Node.js HTTP status codes

Tags: node.js

Where can I find a list of the the [Express](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.status) / Node.js [http.STATUS_CODES](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_status_codes)?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

By opening a terminal and typing

```
$ node
> http.STATUS_CODES
{ '100': 'Continue',
  '101': 'Switching Protocols',
  '102': 'Processing',
  '200': 'OK',
  '201': 'Created',
  '202': 'Accepted',
  '203': 'Non-Authoritative Information',
  '204': 'No Content',
  '205': 'Reset Content',
  '206': 'Partial Content',
  '207': 'Multi-Status',
  '300': 'Multiple Choices',
  '301': 'Moved Permanently',
  '302': 'Moved Temporarily',
  '303': 'See Other',
  '304': 'Not Modified',
  '305': 'Use Proxy',
  '307': 'Temporary Redirect',
  '400': 'Bad Request',
  '401': 'Unauthorized',
  '402': 'Payment Required',
  '403': 'Forbidden',
  '404': 'Not Found',
  '405': 'Method Not Allowed',
  '406': 'Not Acceptable',
  '407': 'Proxy Authentication Required',
  '408': 'Request Time-out',
  '409': 'Conflict',
  '410': 'Gone',
  '411': 'Length Required',
  '412': 'Precondition Failed',
  '413': 'Request Entity Too Large',
  '414': 'Request-URI Too Large',
  '415': 'Unsupported Media Type',
  '416': 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
  '417': 'Expectation Failed',
  '418': 'I\'m a teapot',
  '422': 'Unprocessable Entity',
  '423': 'Locked',
  '424': 'Failed Dependency',
  '425': 'Unordered Collection',
  '426': 'Upgrade Required',
  '428': 'Precondition Required',
  '429': 'Too Many Requests',
  '431': 'Request Header Fields Too Large',
  '500': 'Internal Server Error',
  '501': 'Not Implemented',
  '502': 'Bad Gateway',
  '503': 'Service Unavailable',
  '504': 'Gateway Time-out',
  '505': 'HTTP Version Not Supported',
  '506': 'Variant Also Negotiates',
  '507': 'Insufficient Storage',
  '509': 'Bandwidth Limit Exceeded',
  '510': 'Not Extended',
  '511': 'Network Authentication Required' }
```

This list is based on [RFC 2616 "Status Code Definitions"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Comment: Or `node --print "http.STATUS_CODES"` for short :)

Comment: As a Javascript array: `node --print "JSON.stringify(http.STATUS_CODES, null, 2)" | jq 'keys'` Using [jq](https://jqplay.org/s/NHqXqhelcw)

Comment: Informative but useless in scripts. I don't like to write something like `status.401` in my script. Should be `status.UNAUTHORIZED`

Comment: @Atul `node --print "JSON.stringify(Object.entries(http.STATUS_CODES).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => (acc[value.replace(/ /g, '_')] = key, acc), {}))" | jq '.'`

Comment: `npx http-codes-cli all` will also give you the above map (that's why I wrote it :))